# Show or Hide SlickGrid "header" (filter) row at runtime

Tags: filter, hide, slickgrid, header-row

I'm trying to control the visibility of the HeaderRow at runtime.

[Note:  To clear any confusion: I'm not talking about the row with the column names;  I'm talking about the row that's made visible with grid option "showHeaderRow:true";  i.e., what might be better termed the "Filter Row"].

I'm trying to use:

```
grid.setOptions({ showHeaderRow: true/false }); 
grid.invalidate();
```

This seems to have no effect on the grid or the display of the HeaderRow.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

```
if(grid.getOptions().showHeaderRow){
    grid.setHeaderRowVisibility(false);
}else{
    grid.setHeaderRowVisibility(true);
}
```

Comment: This has a funny animation, what it does internally is basically using jquery to hide and show the header anyway so this might as well be done with vanilla jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this one should be simple enough, I use these 2 pieces of code to hide/show dynamically after the grid is already created.
`grid.hideHeaderRowColumns();` 
`grid.showHeaderRowColumns();`

Give it a try, hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SlickGrid version 2.1 at the time of writing, and I have a similar requirement as yours. After digging some depth into the source code, I assume that option *showHeaderRow* has no effect on the display of the resulting grid unless co-work with the `grid.setHeaderRowVisibility(visibility)`.

Anyway, I managed to work around with simple jquery technique after the grid is created, simply by using the code below, if you don't want any animation:

```
$(".slick-header").hide();
```

Although this is an old question asked 2 years ago, and Slick Grid hasn't got any progress for quite some time, I still believe it's quite a useful lib. Hope this complements the thread and be of a little help for the up-coming users.